# yii2 query database return integer

Tags: mysql, yii2

they can not return the query result as an integer, because I want to save 'id' of the query.

**My Controller**

```html
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
         ->select(['id_citta'])
         ->from('citta')
         ->where(['nome_citta' => 'London'])->one();


         $model->save();
         $viaggio_partenza->id_viaggio = $model->id_viaggio;
         $viaggio_partenza->citta_partenza = $query;
         $viaggio_partenza->save();
```

any suggestions?

```html
public function actionOffri()
   {

    $model = new Viaggi;
    $viaggio_partenza = new ViaggiPartenza;

if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $viaggio_partenza->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){


$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
         ->select(['id_citta'])
         ->from('citta')
         ->where(['nome_citta' => 'Torino'])->one();


         $model->save();
         $viaggio_partenza->id_viaggio = $model->id_viaggio;
         $viaggio_partenza->citta_partenza = $query;
         $viaggio_partenza->save();


}else {....}
```

I would like to retrieve "id_citta" using the query and save it as "citta_partenza", recovery in the form a string that corresponds to integer in the database.

Comment: Can you provide more information about this? I don't quite get it. Where does the query return an integer? After `save()`? And what are you trying to do here?

Comment: What are you doing ? Executing $query ,saving $model and using $query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the single value you should  use scalar() and not one()

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
     ->select(['id_citta'])
     ->from('citta')
     ->where(['nome_citta' => 'London'])->scalar();
```

Scalar() return the first column of the select.. while one() return  the first model (the object related to first row) of the query

or if you need the model

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
     ->select(['id_citta'])
     ->from('citta')
     ->where(['nome_citta' => 'London'])->one();
```

then refer to the attribute

```
   $model->save();
     $viaggio_partenza->id_viaggio = $model->id_viaggio;
     $viaggio_partenza->citta_partenza = $query->id_citta;
     $viaggio_partenza->save();
```

Comment: I do not want to return the column but the integer value it has, I'm sorry but I'm a beginner.

Comment: @saba ..the first column ..(in you case the only column)  is exactly the integer for id_citta  ..(alias is the value you stored  in   citta.citta_id